# Where/filtering in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

I used sql with pyspark but when I used `where` for filtering the result was a empty table but It's false because I have data with this filtering.

`"Lesividad"` is a string:

```
|-- LESIVIDAD: string (nullable = true)



t_acc = spark.sql("SELECT LESIVIDAD, COUNT(LESIVIDAD) AS COUNT FROM acc_table 
                    WHERE LESIVIDAD = 'IL' GROUP BY LESIVIDAD")
t_acc.show()


+---------+-----+
|LESIVIDAD|COUNT|
+---------+-----+
+---------+-----+
```

My table "Lesividad" is:

```
t_acc = spark.sql("""SELECT LESIVIDAD FROM acc_table GROUP BY 
                    LESIVIDAD""").show()
￼



+--------------------+
|           LESIVIDAD|
+--------------------+
|         NO ASIGNADA|
|IL               ...|
|MT               ...|
|HG               ...|
|HL               ...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Seems like `LESIVIDAD = 'IL'` is returning 0 rows. Try `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM acc_table WHERE LESIVIDAD = 'IL').show()` to check.

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect. I presume the  problem is with the data which your trying to search i.e. LESIVIDAD = 'IL'.

Please note, in pyspark, header/column names of table are case-**insensitive** where as data inside the table is **case-****sensitive**. So if your table contains 'il' / 'Il' /'iL' and there is no 'IL'. It will return empty table only.

Hence please note the data which you are trying to search is case-sensitive. Hence type correctly.